# MLFlow doesnt copy properly my artifacts to the mlruns folder when used in a container

Tags: python, docker, mlflow

I am logging a few models using MLflow. The corresponding scripts are executed in a docker container.

The command `mlflow.log_artifacts` doesn't seem to work properly since I can t see the corresponding files under the mlruns folder. The command doesn't return any error though.

EDIT1: after some further investigations, **it seems that the problem arises whenever I mount the folder containing `mlruns/`** as a docker volume.
I did some tests with the example provided by the [docstring](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/blob/4bf54ce9ae22248d2692d2f981e776719a767acf/mlflow/tracking/fluent.py#L565) of `log_artifacts`

```
import os
import json
import mlflow
# Create some files to preserve as artifacts
features = "rooms, zipcode, median_price, school_rating, transport"
data = {"state": "TX", "Available": 25, "Type": "Detached"}
# Create couple of artifact files under the directory "data"
os.makedirs("data", exist_ok=True)
with open("data/data.json", 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
with open("data/features.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write(features)
# Write all files in "data" to root artifact_uri/states
with mlflow.start_run():
    mlflow.log_artifacts("data", artifact_path="states")
```

If I run this in a **container without volume mounting, it runs just fine**, ie the artifacts appear under `mlruns/<exp-id>/<run-id>/artifacts/state`

However If I run this in a container **with the folder containing `mlruns/` mounted, it doesn't work,** ie the folder `mlruns/<exp-id>/<run-id>/artifacts/` is empty.

Answer (score 2):

It took me a while, but I finally found what I was doing wrong here.

The problem arises when you try to add a run executed in a container to an existing experiment that was created locally.

Indeed, when you create a new experience, MLFlow is generated a `meta.yaml` The file looks like this (say you first created the experience locally)

```
artifact_location: file:///Users/greghor/Documents/my-cool-project/mlruns/0
experiment_id: '0'
lifecycle_stage: active
name: Default
```

Assume now, that you want to add a couple of runs under the same experiment. But for some reasons, you don't want to execute them locally, but rather in the `/opt/app` directory of a container.
You have mounted your project dir as a volume because you want to persist the results of your runs once the container is shut down. MLFlow will read the `meta.yml` file instead of creating a new one, and will try to copy the artifacts to a path pointing to your local file system... which won't work.

Surprisingly, MLFlow remains silent while I would expect an error saying that the artifacts dir is not found or something like this.

I don't think there is an easy fix at this stage. If I am not mistaken, MLFlow doesn't expose a method to change the artifact_uri of an existing experiment.
Your best bet is just to make sure that the filesystem of the environment in which you launch the runs is consistent with the `meta.yml` file.

Comment: You are today's [DenverCoder9](https://xkcd.com/979/), except actually helpful :)